# Retrieving substring in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below HTML code:

```
<div class="card-platform">
<span class="sr-only">Hosted at the </span>
<!-- react-text: 365 -->
ANDROID
<!-- /react-text -->
<span class="sr-only"> app store</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to retreive the word "ANDROID". There are many elements which have "ANDROID" value. The other value for the HTML element is "IOS". Few have ANDRIOD and few others have IOS. I want to print what either ANDRIOD/IOS for each element whatever is defined in the HTML.

How to get this value using selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Required text located not inside `"react-text"` tag as that element is just comment, but text is located inside a `div`. You can use below code to get required value:

```
WebElement MyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-platform']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String platformName = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[4].nodeValue", MyText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple exercise in string manipulation:

```
String fullText = driver.findElement(By.className("card-platform")).getText();
assert fullText.equals("Hosted at the \nANDROID\n app store");
String prefix = driver.findElements(By.className("sr-only")).get(0).getText();
String suffix = driver.findElements(By.className("sr-only")).get(1).getText();
assert prefix.equals("Hosted at the ");
assert suffix.equals(" app store");
String yourText = fullText.replace(prefix, "").replace(suffix, "");
assert yourText.equals("ANDROID");
```

Of course you will have to adjust the locators for all your different cases. This is based on the tiny sample of code snippet you provided.

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, I got a number using the code below.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pagina = "https://example"
response = get(pagina)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
cont = soup.find(class_="Trsdu(0.3s)")
print(cont.text)
```

Comment: This is an answer to some other question, so not very useful without explaining the question.